# Which is the correct way to start an Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Let's say the Activity I want to start is named "OccupyThePieShop"

I was previously using this methodology to start an Activity:

```
Intent oTPS = new Intent();
timeIntervalConfigIntent.setClassName("com.aXX3AndSpace.KeepInTouch",
    "com.aXX3AndSpace.KeepInTouch.OccupyThePieShop");
startActivity(oTPS);
```

...but was told that this is more the norm:

```
Intent oTPS = new
    Intent(KeepInTouchActivity.this, OccupyThePieShop.class); 
KeepInTouchActivity.this.startActivity(oTPS);
```

...and so I replaced my calls to `startActivity()` with that usage.

Now, I've come across a couple more ways which seem quite "elegant," namely:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OccupyThePieShop.class));
```

...and:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OccupyThePieShop.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is one way preferred over the others, and if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is probably an issue of personal preference.  I like `startActivity(new Intent(this, OccupyThePieShop.class));` because, as you said, it is elegant.

Comment: Only use `getApplicationContext()` when you **know why you need it**. You never need it for `startActivity()`. Please use `this`.

Comment: Ok. (more characters so SO will let me post this)

Comment: Well, my "elegent" way is not compiling. With this line:

startActivity(new Intent(this, ContactsListListActivity.class));

I get, "The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<ContactsListListActivity>) is undefined"

Comment: This is the only way that will compile:     Intent ktiluca = new Intent(KeepInTouchActivity.this,  KITTimeIntervalLocationUpdateConfigActivity.class);  
    KeepInTouchActivity.this.startActivity(ktiluca);

Comment: Hmm...I'll try to look into this.